# Dreamweaver CS5 Timeline

Tags: windows, dreamweaver, adobe-cs5

Where do you find the timeline in Dreamweaver CS5?

Answer (score 2):

CS5 doesn't include the timeline feature of earlier versions, unfortunately.  I'm trying to figure out a way to import the function from CS3.